# Python IPv6 Regex pattern recognition

Tags: python, regex, ip, ipv6

I have been looking at recognizing IPv6 addresses from strings and replacing them with some other text.

Currently I am using the following pattern:

```
ipv6_pattern = re.compile(r'(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|'
                          r'[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|'
                          r'fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|'
                          r'::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|'
                          r'1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|'
                          r'(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|'
                          r'([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|'
                          r'(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|'
                          r'(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))')
```

It works (almost) ok.

Example:

2001::85a3:0000:0000:8a2e -> CHANGED85a3:0000:0000:8a2e

Clearly I could fix this by adding start and end of string tags to both sides of the regex pattern such that it would cover the whole string instead of only part of it.

This adds a new issue however since there are cases in which a pattern such as

```
STARTOFSTRING2001::85a3:0000:0000:8a2e
STARTOFSTRING2001::85a3:0000:0000:8a2eENDOFSTRING
2001::85a3:0000:0000:8a2eENDOFSTRING
```

and if I add start and end of string tags these cases would not be covered. My question is then as follows:

Is there a "better" pattern I can use that allows me to catch the entire IPv6 address as well as the cases where there is text on either side of it.

Comment: Do you mean that the addresses are concatenated no separation?

Comment: No, I mean that there may be some text before and/or after an address.
2001:: is in itself a valid IPv6 address but im looking to catch the whole address regardless of whether there are text on either sides of it. The addresses appear in a log and there are always atleast a space between two separate addresses

Comment: Take a look at this REgex:    https://gist.github.com/dfee/6ed3a4b05cfe7a6faf40a2102408d5d8

Comment: If you want to make sure there is no digit to the left and to the right of the match add `(?<!\d)` at the start and `(?!\d)` at the end.

Comment: @CharifDZ That implementation works great. If you make it an answer I will mark it correct.